# 7zip Batch-file, Wildcard Compress contents of subfolders

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I have 5000 uniquely named parent folders. Each parent folder contains 5-10 subfolders. I need each subfolder *within* the 5000 folders compressed then deleted, leaving me with one .7z file per subfolder while maintaining the 5000 parent folder's structure.

I have always used the below script for compressing my parent folders. However I am unsure of how to change it to compress all folders *within* the 5000 folders. I assume it will involve some wildcards but extensive google searches have yielded nothing.

```
for /D %%A in (*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z -m9=lzma2 -mx -mmt2 "%%A.7z" -xr!*.bat "%%A"
```

The easiest solution would be to create a bat file to copy the above bat file into each folder, run it, then delete it. However I am assuming 7z has this functionality and I can just not find it.

Edit: Posted the wrong example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an inner loop which will enumerate the subfolders and `rd` to delete them:

```
for /D %%O in (*) do (
    for /D %%I in ("%%O\*") do (
        "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z -m9=lzma2 -mx -mmt2 "%%I.7z" -r -xr!*.bat "%%I"
        rd /s /q "%%I"
    )
)
```

It will preserve absolute paths in the archives, so if you want to exclude the base folder use `cd/d`:

```
for /D %%O in (*) do (
    for /D %%I in ("%%O\*") do (
        pushd "%%~dpnxI"
        "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z -m9=lzma2 -mx -mmt2 "..\%%~nxI.7z" -r -xr!*.bat .
        popd
        rd /s /q "%%~dpnxI"
    )
)
```

Be careful with `rd`, maybe you'll want to do a test run without it.

Comment: Dude you are super patient and awesome at this, wish I had spent more time working bat files, they are super useful and capable! Thanks a ton dude, it's the picture of perfection! Worked great!